# Jax-ws: remove namespace prefix from request object

Tags: jax-ws, jax-ws-customization

I have a problem in Jax-WS in which the service that I expose can't process the following message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Header>
        <CCGW_CUSTOM_HEADER xmlns="">
            <CCGW_CUSTOM_HEADER xmlns="Key">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;&amp;#xD;&lt;CcgwCustomHeaderData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;&amp;#xD; &lt;ClientSystemType&gt;ClientSystem&lt;/ClientSystemType&gt;&amp;#xD;&lt;/CcgwCustomHeaderData&gt;</CCGW_CUSTOM_HEADER>
        </CCGW_CUSTOM_HEADER>
    </S:Header>
    <S:Body>
        <HeartbeatRequest xmlns="http://my-site.com/CCGWCallback">
            <conferenceId>this is a heartbeat</conferenceId>
        </HeartbeatRequest>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

However, the server is able to process this message:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Header>
        <CCGW_CUSTOM_HEADER xmlns="">
            <CCGW_CUSTOM_HEADER xmlns="Key">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;&amp;#xD;&lt;CcgwCustomHeaderData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;&amp;#xD; &lt;ClientSystemType&gt;ClientSystem&lt;/ClientSystemType&gt;&amp;#xD;&lt;/CcgwCustomHeaderData&gt;</CCGW_CUSTOM_HEADER>
        </CCGW_CUSTOM_HEADER>
    </S:Header>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:HeartbeatRequest xmlns:ns2="http://my-site.com/CCGWCallback">
            <conferenceId xmlns="">this is a heartbeat</conferenceId>
        </ns2:HeartbeatRequest>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

What I would like to do is to find a way to remove the **":ns2"** prefix.

I'll appreciate your help.

Nadav